# Test Executed right after build atuomatically

Tags: specflow

I have few tests in my solution and for some reason today my tests were getting executed when i was building my solution.
It builds and then start test execution , I am not sure why?
Can anyone help me in this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It could be, that you have "Run tests after build" in the Test Explorer activated.

[image: Test Explorer upper left corner]

Comment: Thank you so much Andreas :) I have am looking for options to use Profile files in Specflow. If you have some ideas or links please share.